# Show that for $r,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $r \geq n$, $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{r+n-i-1}{r} = \binom{r-1}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Show that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{r+n-i-1}{r} = \binom{r-1}{n-1}$$
where $r,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $r \geq n$.

Comment: Can you please edit your post in order to show us what you've been trying? Otherwise, no one will solve your exercise for you ;)

Comment: Please read: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ; And: There is no indication whether the question should be answered combinatorially or analytically.

Comment: See also: [Proving $\binom {n-1}{r-1}=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom r k \binom{n+r-k-1}{r-k-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234684)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** ${ r+k-1 \choose r} = {r +k-1 \choose k-1} $ is the number of ways to distribute $r$ identical things amongst $k$ people.

**Hint:** The $(-1)^n {n\choose i}$ is very reminiscent of Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

**Hint:** How many ways are there to distribute $r$ identical things amongst $k$ people, so that [CONDITION X] is equal to the LHS and RHS?