# Calculate chosen element of this Number Pyramid

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, factorial, binomial-theorem

### Introduction

Lets choose a natural number $n$ and generate a sequence $ k_1, k_2, k_3, ... k_n $ where each $k_n$ is replaced using $ f(k_a)= (a+1)^n - a^n $

The sequence then is $ (2^n-1), (3^n-2^n),(4^n-3^n),\dots,((n+1)^n-n^n).   $

---

Let now for example $n=5$

The sequence is then: $31, 211,781,2101,4651$

Now lets build a number pyramid where the item in the next row is made by subtracting the two numbers behind it (basicly like when using a number pyramid to find the next number in a sequence if possible):

$$ (31) (211) (781) (2101) (4651) $$

$$ (180) (570) (1320) (2550) $$

$$ (390) (750) (1230) $$

$$ (360) (480) $$

$$ (120) $$

By expanding our pyramid with the 6th element in the first/top/longest row; its $9031$ and by climbing upwards the same way it gives us another $120$ at the last/bottom row which tells us that the pyramid is complete since the last row starts repeating.

The 120, or the *last element* (the one that completes the pyramid where $n=5$) is also $5!$

In general, for any natural $n$, we can generate a pyramid like this with $n$ rows and $n$ elements in the first row, and the $n!$ in the last row alone.

From this I concluded that $ n!=(n+1)^n-nn^n+\binom n2(n-1)^n-\dots $ which I was wondering about in my previous question: [Expressing Factorials with Binomial Coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673539/expressing-factorials-with-binomial-coefficients)

---

I then have concluded that for all pyramids in general (where $n\ge2$ so it can have at least 2 rows) that the element $m$ in the row before the last one can be calculated using $$(\frac{n+(2m-1)}{2})n!$$

I then have concluded that the first element in the *row before the one that is before the last one* (or simply third from the bottom) can be calculated with $$ \frac{(3n^2+n+2)}{24}n! $$

And these 2 conclusions have been made by experimenting and comparing different pyramids.

---

### Question

Instead of trying to find connections between the elements and writing formulas and expressions for elements in each row like I did with the previous two conclusions, how would one "create" a formula, something like $F(x,y,n)=...$ to calculate the $x$th element in the $y$th row for a pyramid $n$ of this type ($n$ rows) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using more readable notation: $u_{n}(k)=(k+1)^{n}-k^{n}$ for $k=1,\ldots, n$

Now $u_{n-1}(k)=u_{n}(k+1)-u_{n}(k)=(k+2)^{n}-2(k+1)^{n}+k^{n}$ for $k=1,\ldots, n-1$

$u_{n-2}(k)=(k+3)^{n}-3(k+2)^{n}+3(k+1)^{n}-k^{n}$ for $k=1,\ldots, n-2$

For $j=0,\ldots, n-1$,

$u_{n-j}(k)=(k+j+1)^{n}-\binom{j+1}{1}(k+j)^{n}+\binom{j+1}{2}(k+j-1)^{n}-\ldots+(-1)^{j+1}k^{n}$

where $k=1,\ldots, n-j$

What I've observed:

$u_{1}(1)=n!$ for $n\geq 1$

$u_{2}(k)=n!\left( k+\frac{n-1}{2} \right)$  for $n\geq 2$

$u_{3}(k)=n!\left( \frac{k^{2}}{2}+\frac{n-2}{2}k+\frac{(n-2)(3n-5)}{24} \right)$ for $n\geq 3$

$u_{4}(k)=n!\left( \frac{k^{3}}{6}+\frac{n-3}{4}k^{2}+\frac{(n-3)(3n-8)}{24}k+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)^{2}}{48} \right)$ for $n\geq 4$